# How to leverage BigQuery foreign keys?

Tags: google-bigquery

This article showcases the use of BigQuery FOREIGN KEYs (NOT ENFORCED).

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/join-optimizations-with-bigquery-primary-and-foreign-keys?hl=en

I cannot reproduce what is shown in the article. This is what I ran to prepare the data:

```
CREATE TABLE test.items (
  id INT64,
  descritpion STRING,
  PRIMARY KEY (id) NOT ENFORCED
);

INSERT INTO test.items VALUES
(2, "abc"),
(3, "def"),
(4, "gih"),
(5, "klm"),
(6, "nop");

CREATE TABLE test.inventory (
  item_id INT64 REFERENCES test.items(id) NOT ENFORCED,
  warehouse_id INT64,
  quantity INT64,
  PRIMARY KEY(item_id, warehouse_id) NOT ENFORCED
);

INSERT INTO test.inventory VALUES
(1, 1, 0),
(2, 1, 1),
(3, 1, 10),
(4, 1, 10),
(5, 1, 3),
(6, 1, 2),
(1, 2, 4),
(2, 2, 5),
(3, 2, 3),
(4, 2, 0),
(5, 2, 13),
(6, 2, 12);
```

Then:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `test.items` AS items
INNER JOIN
  `test.inventory` AS inventory ON items.id = inventory.item_id
WHERE RAND() < 2  # Prevents BigQuery to use cached results
```

I would have expected the execution graph to look like in the article: flattened. But it's not the case.

[image]

What am I missing here?